# Как реализовать систему верификации действий?

Tags: python, криптография, verification

Стоит предупредить, что в качестве фреймворка используется Django. К вопросу прямого отношения этот факт не имеет, но решил уточнить на всякий случай.

Стоит задача реализовать систему, которая, при осуществлении каких-либо действий, требует от пользователя подтверждения личности. Легчайший пример - подтверждение регистрации.

Необходимо реализовать слой, ответственный за генерацию токенов\кодов.

У меня в голове несколько реализаций:

1. Можно генерировать шестизначные цифровые коды и заставлять пользователя вводить их, после чего валидировать(не просрочен ли код и т.д).
2. Можно генерировать токены и подставлять их в ссылку, при переходе по которой личность пользователя будет подтверждена.

Меня интересует безопасное решение, при котором пользователю будет удобно. Я не разбираюсь в этом и прошу максимально конкретизировать. Подскажите, возможно, какие-то инструменты для этого. Если честно, то у меня возникают сложности даже с тем, чтобы теги соответствующие разместить, так что надеюсь на ваши правки.

Comment: Оба ваших варианта принципиально не отличаются ничем. Цифровой код - это тоже токен, просто короткий

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется то что вы ищете называется [jwt-токены](https://habr.com/ru/post/340146/)
На Django я бы рекомендовал использовать библиотеку [djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html), которая является middleware(посредником) между запросами из интернета и вашим приложением и предоставляет авторизацию через [jwt-токены](https://habr.com/ru/post/340146/)

Comment: Возможно, что это действительно jwt-токены. Но мне токены необходимы не для системы аутентификации, а для отправки их пользователю, чтобы он мог осуществлять такие действия, как, например, сброс пароля.

Comment: @CrazyTheory в Django уже есть встроенная система сброса пароля с токенами https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/

Comment: это я указал просто для примера, в сервисах ведь приходится верифицировать не только сброс пароля, а и ряд других действий: регистрация, сброс пароля, изменение пароля, юзернейма, почты. Я так понял, что вы предлагаете использовать для этих целей django.contrib.auth.tokens.PasswordResetTokenGenerator?

Comment: Если детально то да